# play-grpc: AkkaGrpcClientModule is not generated

Tags: playframework, grpc, akka-grpc

I'm trying to set test project with play framework and grpc.

My `build.sbt`:

```
enablePlugins(AkkaGrpcPlugin)

import play.grpc.gen.scaladsl.PlayScalaServerCodeGenerator
akkaGrpcExtraGenerators += PlayScalaServerCodeGenerator

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "com.lightbend.play" %% "play-grpc-runtime" % "0.9.1"
)
```

`plugins.sbt`:

```
addSbtPlugin("com.lightbend.akka.grpc" % "sbt-akka-grpc" % "1.0.2")

resolvers += Resolver.bintrayRepo("playframework", "maven")

libraryDependencies += "com.lightbend.play" %% "play-grpc-generators" % "0.9.1"
```

proto:

```
syntax = "proto3";

package com.example.protos;

// The greeting service definition.
service Greeter {
  // Sends a greeting
  rpc SayHello (HelloRequest) returns (HelloReply) {}
}

// The request message containing the user's name.
message HelloRequest {
  string name = 1;
}

// The response message containing the greetings
message HelloReply {
  string message = 1;
}
```

Now according to the documentation: https://developer.lightbend.com/docs/play-grpc/current/play/consuming-grpc.html this setup should also generate `AkkaGrpcClientModule` for me but it doesn't happen.
This is the list of generated artifacts:

```
AbstractGreeterRouter
DefaultGreeterClient
Greeter
GreeterClient
GreeterClientPowerApi
GreeterHandler$
HelloProto$
HelloReply
HelloRequest
```

Did I miss anything in my setup?

Answer (score 0):

Stupid me, this was missing:

```
akkaGrpcExtraGenerators += PlayScalaClientCodeGenerator
```

Comment: May I ask what version of play-framework you are using?

Comment: I use play 2.7.*